# Undefined username when set a cookie

Tags: cookies

I am trying to set a cookie to my website, all steps are going well except when I check if the cookie isset, when I add this condition `|| isset($_COOKIE['username'])` it undefines the index `username` in the next line, is there any mistake in the if statement?

```
if (isset($_SESSION['username']) || isset($_COOKIE['username'])) {
$userLoggedIn = $_SESSION['username'];
$user_details_query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$userLoggedIn'");
$user = mysqli_fetch_array($user_details_query);
}
else {
$userLoggedIn = NULL; 
}
```

Comment: Maybe you set the username in cookie. But you try to get it from session, aren’t you?

Comment: I reviewd the code after your comment, it seems that I am setting 2 usernames one in cookie and one in session, and getting the one from session, I am lost now :)

Comment: Which language is that? PHP?

Comment: yes, PHP, actually I solved it by making if loops one to get the username from cookie, and one from the session, and it worked perfectly, thank you